# Multiplayer Game Tournament Generator

Tags: algorithm

If I have a multiplayer game that requires 6 people per game, and I have 100 tournament participants, what is the best algorithm I can use to assign people to games such that everyone plays each other at least once, while minimizing the number of games players will play someone they've already played?

Essentially, is there a way to generate a round robin tournament for multiplayer games? I'm thinking about using this algorithm for a Catan tournament.

Comment: Now this is an interesting question! Why don't you just play all the 1.192B possible games that can be played? (Joke). Just to be clear, say player 1 plays in the first game with players 2-6. Later player 1 would have to play in different games with all players 7-100 to complete the round robin. Correct? And that would be the same for every other player.

Comment: Are there rounds and than that same player cannot play twice in a round , please specify this otherwise your question is too broad

Comment: jch: Correct.


Vikram: There are rounds and that same player cannot play twice in a round. Does this make a significant difference?

Answer (score 2):

One of the ways to approach the related Social Golfer problem is local search. Some of the proposed methods have been very sophisticated. The C program below is not; it picks a random initial schedule and makes random swaps that do not increase the number of pairs of players who do not play. At least 21 rounds are needed for 100 players and groups of 6 (some player sits out a round, then needs ceil((100 - 1) / (6 - 1)) = 20 rounds to play everyone), so 27 isn't too far off the optimum, though I'm sure it's possible to do better with more sophisticated optimization techniques.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
  GAMENUMPLAYER = 6,
  NUMPLAYER = 100,
  ROUNDNUMPLAYER = NUMPLAYER - NUMPLAYER % GAMENUMPLAYER,
  NUMROUND = 27
};

static int Schedule[NUMROUND][NUMPLAYER];
static int Numgame[NUMPLAYER][NUMPLAYER];
static int Numunplayed = (NUMPLAYER * (NUMPLAYER - 1)) / 2;

static void count(int r, int i, int delta) {
  int start;
  int stop;
  int j;
  if (i >= ROUNDNUMPLAYER) return;
  start = i - i % GAMENUMPLAYER;
  stop = start + GAMENUMPLAYER;
  for (j = start; j < stop; j++) {
    int p;
    int q;
    if (j == i) continue;
    p = Schedule[r][i];
    q = Schedule[r][j];
    if (q < p) {
      int t;
      t = p;
      p = q;
      q = t;
    }
    if (Numgame[p][q] == 0) Numunplayed--;
    Numgame[p][q] += delta;
    if (Numgame[p][q] == 0) Numunplayed++;
  }
}

static void swap(int r, int i, int j) {
  int t;
  count(r, i, -2);
  count(r, j, -2);
  t = Schedule[r][i];
  Schedule[r][i] = Schedule[r][j];
  Schedule[r][j] = t;
  count(r, i, 2);
  count(r, j, 2);
}

static void validate(void) {
  int nu;
  int q;
  nu = 0;
  for (q = 0; q < NUMPLAYER; q++) {
    int p;
    for (p = 0; p < q; p++) {
      int ng;
      int r;
      ng = 0;
      for (r = 0; r < NUMROUND; r++) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < ROUNDNUMPLAYER; i++) {
          int k;
          if (Schedule[r][i] != p) continue;
          for (k = 0; k < GAMENUMPLAYER; k++) {
            if (Schedule[r][i - i % GAMENUMPLAYER + k] == q) ng++;
          }
        }
      }
      assert(ng * 2 == Numgame[p][q]);
      assert(Numgame[p][q] >= 0);
      if (Numgame[p][q] == 0) nu++;
    }
  }
  assert(nu == Numunplayed);
}

int main(void) {
  int r;
  for (r = 0; r < NUMROUND; r++) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMPLAYER; i++) {
      int j;
      j = rand() % (i + 1);
      Schedule[r][i] = Schedule[r][j];
      Schedule[r][j] = i;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < NUMPLAYER; i++) count(r, i, 1);
  }
  while (Numunplayed > 0) {
    int r;
    int i;
    int j;
    int previous;
    r = rand() % NUMROUND;
    i = rand() % NUMPLAYER;
    j = rand() % NUMPLAYER;
    previous = Numunplayed;
    swap(r, i, j);
    if (Numunplayed < previous) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%d\n", Numunplayed);
    } else if (Numunplayed > previous) {
      swap(r, i, j);
    }
  }
  for (r = 0; r < NUMROUND; r++) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < NUMPLAYER; i++) {
      if (i > 0) putchar(i % GAMENUMPLAYER == 0 ? ';' : ',');
      printf("%d", Schedule[r][i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Very nice solution.  Was NUMROUND = 27 just a reasonable guess that was close to 21?  I translated to Java to execute.

Comment: @jch I set it using trial and error -- any lower and I get impatient waiting for convergence.